# Official Installation guide for substrate

Tags: substrate

I am trying to learn how to use substrate on a mac. The first step in the guide is to execute

"# Install Homebrew if necessary https://brew.sh/
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

## Make sure Homebrew is up-to-date, install openssl and cmake

brew update
brew install openssl cmake"

However, when I execute it, it asks for a password. I have tried assigning a sudo password but I am not exactly sure how to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not a Mac user, but here you need to have admin (sudo) authority in the system. This on Linux is very likely your main user, and `root` supersedes this. For a sudo password on mac, try your user's login password on promting

Comment: Are you building on M1 Apple silicon? you will have more issues, here is how to get around them: https://vikiival.medium.com/run-substrate-on-apple-m1-a2699743fae8